# Why did my footprints build failed?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, imagery, mosaic-dataset

[image]

As I am trying to add raster to my mosaic dataset and were able to see them and now all of my raster are not showing.

Why did it could not build a footprints ? I have tried everthing to get them restore back...

Comment: Have you looked at row 263 and 280? Can the rasters be located or are they missing on the filesystem? Is their spatial reference different to the others? There is an unsolved post here https://geonet.esri.com/thread/85097 that may help but probably wont.

Comment: Thanks. no, I had to re-do all over and got it right this time. I have post it similiar here https://geonet.esri.com/thread/125045

Comment: Perhaps put that in as an answer: Don't try to fix it, just delete it and rebuild it again. Sometimes 'give up and start again' is good information to get, especially if it saves hours/days of trying to fix a problem that doesn't have a solution.